# Root Property in angular.json file

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend

What is the value of “root” property in the angular.json file, for the main project of your angular workspace?

Answer (score 1):

> The root folder for this project's files, relative to the workspace folder. Empty for the initial app, which resides at the top level of the workspace.

If you create a workspace with multiple projects, this can usually be like

```
"project": [
   "myProject1": {
     "root": "projects/myProject1",
     "...": "...",
    },
    "myProject2": {
     "root": "projects/myProject2",
     "...": "...",
    }
```

https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config